# Can't figure out how to print a list in this correct order

Tags: java

Basically I have an arraylist of objects which have a name and startDate and they are in a similar initial order to :

Frank 10/20/1990

Bill 1/2/1990

Frank 2/2/1990

John 9/8/1990

Bill 4/4/1990

Frank 5/1/1990

I'm trying to print them in order of the first names declared and then by date, eg, the final printing should print :

Frank 1/1/1990

Frank 5/1/1990

Frank 10/20/1990

Bill 1/2/1990

Bill 4/4/1990

John 9/8/1990

Comment: *"I'm trying to print them in order of the first names declared and then by date"* - What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have two basic problems, both which have been solved before.  The first is, how would you sort a `String` representing a date and, how would you sort a object based on more then one property

Comment: I have added two different solutions to your problem to my answer, as I was not sure what you exactly wanted. Maybe you could clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you object class looks like this:

```
private static class MyObject {

  private final String name;
  private final Date date;

  private MyObject(String name, Date date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }
}
```

You could print your objects using the following method:

```
@Test
public void printInOrder() {
  List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>(); // List containing your objects
  list.add(new MyObject("Frank", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 10, 20).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Bill", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 1, 2).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Frank", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 2, 2).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("John", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 9, 8).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Bill", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 4, 4).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Frank", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 5, 1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));

  list.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getName)
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getDate)))
      .map(obj -> obj.getName() + " " + obj.getDate())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

> Bill Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 1990
>   Bill Wed Apr 04 00:00:00 CEST 1990
>   Frank Fri Feb 02 00:00:00 CET 1990
>   Frank Tue May 01 00:00:00 CEST 1990
>   Frank Sat Oct 20 00:00:00 CET 1990
>   John Sat Sep 08 00:00:00 CEST 1990

---

This uses Java 8 streams and a comparator chain to sort your objects. The comparators compare by a given attribute, the `thenComparing` is used to chain them.

---

**UPDATE:**

As I am not sure if I possibly misunderstood you, here is a second version for the following case:

You want to sort by name, but in the order the **names are appearing in the original list**, so names first appearing will be first.

In this case you will have to remember the order of the names in a separate, temporary list (only containing the unique names in the original order) that can be used inside the comparator afterwards.

This list is produced by transforming the original list into a set (so have only the unique names) and then transforming this set back into a list (to be able to use `indexOf` inside the comparator).

```
@Test
public void printInOrder() {
  List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(new MyObject("Frank", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 10, 20).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Bill", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 1, 2).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Frank", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 2, 2).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("John", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 9, 8).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Bill", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 4, 4).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
  list.add(new MyObject("Frank", Date.from(LocalDate.of(1990, 5, 1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));

  List<String> declaredNameOrder = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
                                      .map(MyObject::getName)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));

  list.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.<MyObject>comparingInt(o -> declaredNameOrder.indexOf(o.getName()))
                  .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getDate)))
      .map(obj -> obj.getName() + " " + obj.getDate())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

> Frank Fri Feb 02 00:00:00 CET 1990
>   Frank Tue May 01 00:00:00 CEST 1990
>   Frank Sat Oct 20 00:00:00 CET 1990
>   Bill Tue Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 1990
>   Bill Wed Apr 04 00:00:00 CEST 1990
>   John Sat Sep 08 00:00:00 CEST 1990

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in two steps:

First order by name using custom comparator like:

```
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
       public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
          return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
       }
    });
```

And store the output in a temp list

Second use temp list to sort by data:

```
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
       public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
           return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
       }
    });
```

then your list will be sorted as you want.

Comment: Wouldn't this order it by alphabetical order? I can't figure out how to get it to print all of the objects with the first name that got declared first instead of just alphabetical order